# Magento update: Archiving Customizations and Extensions

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.8.0.0

I am trying to update magento ce-1.4.0.1 to ce-1.8. Following the [guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee11302-ce18-install-upgrade#prereq-tasks-prod-archive) I am suposed to

> Archive any custom theme packages in the
>   magento-install-dir/app/design/frontend and
>   magento-install-dir/skin/frontend directories.

Does this include `base` and `default` folders? I guess the update will change these files so I would not include them but on the other hand some modules might have added files here.

What would be the best way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dpending on you changed something in them, you should backup them, but not recover them.

Better is, if you diff against a 1.4.0.1 to check for modifications, if you find one, you need to handle them, if everything is old, you don't need to backup them.

Comment: Ok, I get an original 1.4.0.1 and run diff. Thanks!